# Should I use desktop or server version for my own java+mysql trading system?

Tags: java, mysql

I am going to build a trading system with java and mysql but I am not sure should I use desktop or server version. The backtest part would involve a lot of calculation and live trade part requests stability and quick response timing.

Comment: If it's a server, then use Ubuntu Server. But apart from the default package selection nothing is different, really. Not even the kernel. Running a GUI is not the best thing for a system that has to perform background tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

So you are setting up a trading system using that machine as a server? And then people can connect using a website or something like that? Well, then I would definitely choose Ubuntu Server.

Comment: just for myself, no one else would use it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is to be a dedicated server, then I would definitely recommend using a long-term supported release of Ubuntu Server. On the other hand, if you plan to run your services alongside personal applications (e.g. on your desktop or laptop), I would recommend using a long-term supported release of Ubuntu Desktop. Installing a command line system from an Alternate image is also a good choice if you want more control over how much resources your system consumes on its own graphics and - in a production context - other bloatware.

Either way, before you try to run any GNU/Linux-based service in a production environment, make sure you know how to [use the terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) properly and how to [keep your system up to date](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/package-management.html).